# Is there a backup software for external hard drive working on both Ubuntu and Windows?

Tags: hard-drive, backup, deja-dup

I couldn't find an appropriate thread discussing all the things at once so I'm going to ask here.

1. I need something to backup 500GB worth of files to an external 2TB hard drive.
2. I prefer some backup software which will help me do some kind of sync.
3. I also want the files to be directly accessible from anywhere.

I know that `deja-dup` won't help me because the stored files are somewhat compressed and in a backup format so that you cannot directly access them (however the sync ability is really cool).

Just copying the files is an option but there is no sugars like automatic backups or sync.

Comment: Rsync (linux) and cwRsync for windoze.

Comment: @User24601 thanks, seems like the thing i need.

Comment: If you're happy with that, I'll post it as answer if you'd care to accept it...

Comment: @User24601 Sure, it worked wonders.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For both Ubuntu (Linux) and Windows you will be hard pressed to find anything which matches the simplicity and capability of Rsync for Linux and cwRsync for Windows.

> Rsync, or Remote Sync, is a free command-line tool that lets you
> transfer files and directories to local and remote destinations. Rsync
> is used for mirroring, performing backups, or migrating data to other
> servers.
>
> cwRsync is an implementation of rsync for Windows. rsync uses a file
> transfer technology specified by the rsync algorithm, transferring
> only changed chunks of files over the network. cwRsync can be used for
> remote file backup and synchronization from/to Windows systems.